# Can we migrate rich-text-field-data between environments?

Tags: data-loader, data-export, richtextarea, data-migration

After searching on the SFSE website, it seems this question hasn't been asked.

Can we migrate rich text field data between environments?

Most records contain images embedded in rich text fields which show up as

```
<img src="Long image URL which is not publicly accessible" />
```

within the exported CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has very straight answer, No. Becasue images are hosted in separate authenticated server instance so, you cannot access those images in different environment so, it doesn't work.

There is a work around. If you can encode image in `base64` then you will be able to access those images as they are independent of server now.

I found this link:
http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/converting-a-rich-text-area-fields-image-for-api-upload

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if you need it now but there is a tool special for this from Xappex named [XL CONNECTOR](https://www.xappex.com/docs/enabler4excel/basic-features/mass-import-export-of-images-stored-in-rich-text-area-fields-in-salesforce/).
For Mass Import/Export of images stored in Rich Text Area fields in Salesforce.
The task of mass downloading/uploading of images from/to Salesforce Rich Text Area fields just got a lot easier:
Because the pictures aren't just a link, but pictures ! You can see the tutorial on the websites, I didn't code that but that helps me so I share.
If that can help you enjoy it !
best regards

Comment: Can you explain the specific steps of how this tool can do what the OP is asking?